# Fetching PDF file content into NSString

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am working on iPad application in which i have to show PDF data into table. Firstly,I want to fetch  PDF file content into NSString, how to achieve this. I tried a lot but i am  unable to get it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Quartz2d**. 
Check t[his page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-TPXREF101) of the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1), it covers everything you need to open and parse a PDF file in iOS. Note that it is not a simple task, since there's no method to extract the full text in one line. You have to work with the data as an input stream, using a `CGPDFScanner`